# VBS time range with hours and minutes

Tags: vbscript

I need to run a vbs script based on a time range of between 10:05 AM and 20:30 PM. This is my current code:

```
If Hour(Now()) >= 10 OR hour(Now()) < 20 Then
   WScript.Echo "Time Range"

Else

   WScript.Echo "NOT Time Range"

End If
```

But i'm struggling with the minutes parts.
Reviewing the Minute Function documentation for VBS wasn't so clear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Time()` function to retrieve current time and check against time literals or if you need to use strings (ex. retrieve configuration from somewhere) you can use the `CDate` function to retrieve the time

```
Dim startTime, endTime

    ' Using time literals    
    If InTime( #10:05#, #20:30# ) Then 
        WScript.Echo "In time range"
    Else
        WScript.Echo "NOT in time range"
    End If 

    ' Using strings
    If InTime( CDate("10:05") , CDate("20:30") ) Then 
        WScript.Echo "In time range"
    Else
        WScript.Echo "NOT in time range"
    End If 


' Logic moved to a function to avoid duplication in previous samples    
Function InTime( startTime, endTime )
Dim currentTime
    currentTime = Time()
    InTime = CBool( ( currentTime >= startTime ) And ( currentTime <= endTime ) )
End Function
```

**edited** to adapt to comments

OP asked why `And` and not `Or` when checking time range. While the case in the question should be handled with `And` (current time must be greater than start time **`And`** lower than end time), there is a case where `Or` must be used: when the time range to check starts before midnight and ends pass it. If this is the case, the condition changes

```
Option Explicit 

Dim startTime, endTime

    ' Using time literals
    If InTime( #10:05#, #20:30# ) Then 
        WScript.Echo "In time range"
    Else
        WScript.Echo "NOT in time range"
    End If 

    ' Using strings
    If InTime( CDate("10:05") , CDate("20:30") ) Then 
        WScript.Echo "In time range"
    Else
        WScript.Echo "NOT in time range"
    End If 

    ' Check over midnight
    If InTime( #20:30# , #10:05# ) Then 
        WScript.Echo "In time range"
    Else
        WScript.Echo "NOT in time range"
    End If 

' Logic moved to a function to avoid duplication in previous samples 
Function InTime( startTime, endTime )
Dim currentTime
    currentTime = Time()

    If startTime <= endTime Then 
        ' If startTime <= endTime both are in same day 
        '   current time should be 
        '       greater than startTime 
        '       AND lower than endTime
        '
        '                        >----------------------------<
        '  0.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10.11.12.13.14.15.16.17.18.19.20.21.22.23.
        '
        InTime = CBool( ( currentTime >= startTime ) And ( currentTime <= endTime ) )
    Else 
        ' startTime > endTime when both times don't belong to same day
        '   current time should be 
        '       greater than start time (towards midnight) 
        '       OR lower than end time (backwards to midnight)
        '
        '                         >---------|--------------------<
        '  13.14.15.16.17.18.19.20.21.22.23.0.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10.11.12.
        '
        '  ----------------------<                             >---------
        '  0.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10.11.12.13.14.15.16.17.18.19.20.21.22.23.
        '
        InTime = CBool( ( currentTime >= startTime ) Or ( currentTime <= endTime ) )
    End If 
End Function
```

Comment: shouldn't i use Or instead of And?

Comment: @edwio, to be inside the range current time must be greater than start point AND lower than end point.